# ggplot2, one barplot, multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on coding qualitative data from a survey and I'm trying to make one ggplot2 barplot.

The items are opened-ended questions. For example, one question/item is 'what mental health services does your community provide?'.

Each questions/items such as that example, are columns in my data table. For each item I created additional columns to code the original open-ended responses as dichotomous response variables.

For example for the question/item 'what mental health services does your community provide?', I created three additional columns

'services provided by emergency departments',
'services provided by  clinics',
and 'services provided by schools'.

If a responder endorsed any of these three sub-categories in their open-ended response, I would code a 'yes, if not, a 'no'.

So I have five columns, one id, one containing the original open-ended question, and three sub-category columns coded as yes or no for each person.

```
df<-structure(list(id = 1:20, other_mh_services = c("school services and emergency room", 
"mental health clinic", "mental health clinic and schools services", 
"none", "mental health clinic", "school services and emergency room", 
"mental health clinic", "mental health clinic and schools services", 
"none", "mental health clinic", "school services and emergency room", 
"mental health clinic", "mental health clinic and schools services", 
"none", "mental health clinic", "school services and emergency room", 
"mental health clinic", "mental health clinic and schools services", 
"none", "mental health clinic"), school = c("yes", "no", "yes", 
"no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", 
"no", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no"), er = c("yes", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", 
"no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"), clinic = c("no", 
"yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", 
"yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes", "no", "yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

e.g.

| ID | Item1. Other mental health services? | Item1. school | Item1.ER | Item1.clinic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | school services and emergency room | yes | yes | no |
| 2 | mental health clinic | no | no | yes |
| 3 | mental health clinic and schools services | yes | no | yes |
| 4 | none | no | no | no |

I'd like to create one barplot, or histogram, which has each item subcategory (columns 3-5) on the x axis, and on the y axis, the number of people who responded 'yes'.
[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7WAS.png)

Any suggestions on how to do that in ggplot2?

Comment: Welcome. Please share an example of your data using ``dput(data)`` and paste the output into the original question. Thanks.

Comment: You should provide your data so we can help you. You are probably better off with a barplot than an histogram. Histograms are better suited for continuous variables. Factor variables with 2-3 levels are poorly represented in histograms. You should also ask specific programming questions in order to be on-topic in SO.

Comment: Ok thanks, I added some info about my data, but I'm new at this so if you have advice on how to better show my data please let me know. Yes, I think a barplot would be nice. I'm looking for some example code on how to produce one ggplot barplot that includes each of three sub-category variables that I coded based on my original open-ended question. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post to explain further and provide reproducible data

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper reproducible dataset I can only make an educated guess on what you want.

I made this data up where we two possible answers to answer the question (ER or School)

```
df<-data.frame(ID = seq(1:100), question = seq(1:100), School = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100),
               ER = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100))
```

I also created a small data frame with all possible combinations of these answers (4 answer types). I then label these as A, B,C, or D. I also add a column where I designate each answer based on 1 or 0 (1 being yes, 0 being no)

```
possible_combinations<-unique(df[, c("School", "ER")])
possible_combinations$combo_type<-c("A", "B", "C", "D")
possible_combinations$combos<-paste(possible_combinations$School,possible_combinations$ER)
```

I want to fill in the original dataset with markers indicating which questions had which combinations of answers based on the possible combinations above so I make an empty column in the original dataset:

```
df$combo<-NA
```

Now I simply run a for loop that checks the combinations of actual answers to the previously established combinations and fill in this empty column with either A, B,C, or D.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  combo<-paste(df$School[i], df$ER[i])
  df$combo[i]<-possible_combinations$combo_type[which(possible_combinations[,4] %in% combo)]
}
```

Now it's just a matter of plotting with bar plots using ggplot after summarising the total counts of each answer based on unique combinations:

```
df %>% group_by(combo) %>%
  summarise(total = n()) %>% ggplot(.) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(x = combo, y = total), width =0.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Final plot]

Comment: Thanks so much, I may end up plotting it the way you suggested. Very helpful. I edited my original post...hopefully this time you can reproduce the data and you can see what type of plot I'm looking to create.